# BigQuery (Google Analytics data):query two different 'hits.customDimensions.index' in the same 'hits.hitNumber'

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

> **my goal:**

Count 1 for the session if the following two hits.customDimensions.index and associated hits.customDimensions.value appear in the same hits.hitNumber (every row is 1 session if main query is still nested):

['hits.customDimensions.index' = 43  with associated 'hits.customDimensions.value'  IN ('login', 'payment', 'order', 'thankyou')] AND ['hits.customDimensions.index' = 10  with associated 'hits.customDimensions.value' = 'checkout' [in the same hits.hitNumber]

> **my problem**:

I don't know how i can query two different hits.customDimensions.value in the same hits.hitNumber in one Subquery without different WITH-tables. If it's possible, which I'm sure, the query would be very easy and short. Since i don't know how to query this usecase in a subquery, I use an workaround which totals to 5 WITH-tables. **I would appreciate an easy way to query this usecase**

> **Explanation workaround query:**

Table1: Queries all except the 'problem-metric'

Table2-3: Each table queries one hits.customDimensions.index with  associated hits.customDimensions.value filtered for the correct value, sessionId and hitNumber

table4: left join table 2 with table 3 based on date, sessionID and hitNumber. Basically if hitNumber combined with sessionId from table2 and table3 match I count 1

table5: left join table1 with table4 to combine the data

```
#Table1 - complete data except session_atleast_loginCheckout
WITH
  prepared_data AS (
  SELECT
    date,
    SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE CAST(eCommerceAction.action_type AS INT64) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 LIMIT 1)) AS sessions_atleast_basket, 
    #insert in this row query for sessions_atleast_loginCheckout
    SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcd WHERE index = 43 AND value IN ('payment', 'order', 'thankyou') LIMIT 1)) AS sessions_atleast_payment,
  FROM
    `big-query-221916.172008714.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND totals.visits = 1 
  GROUP BY
    date


#Table2 - data for hits.customDimensions.index = 10 AND associated hits.customDimensions.value = 'checkout' with hits.hitNumber and sessionId (join later based on hitNumber and sessionId)
loginCheckout_index10_pagetype_data AS (
  SELECT
    date AS date,
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId, '/', CAST( visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS sessionId,
    h.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
    IF(hcd.value IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL) AS pagetype_checkout
  FROM
    `big-query-221916.172008714.ga_sessions_*` AS o, UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcd
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND hcd.index = 10 AND VALUE = 'checkout'  AND h.type = 'PAGE' AND totals.visits = 1),


#Table3 - data for hits.customDimensions.index = 43 AND associated hits.customDimensions.value IN ('login', 'register', 'payment', 'order','thankyou') with hits.hitNumber and sessionId (join later based on hitNumber and sessionId)
loginCheckout_index43_pagelevel1_data AS (
  SELECT
    date AS date,
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId, '/', CAST( visitStartTime AS STRING)) AS sessionId,
    h.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
    IF(hcd.value IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL) AS pagelevel1_login_to_thankyou
  FROM
    `big-query-221916.172008714.ga_sessions_*` AS o, UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcd
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND hcd.index = 43 AND VALUE IN ('login', 'register', 'payment', 'order', 'thankyou') AND h.type = 'PAGE'  
),


#table4 - left join table2 and table 3 on sessionId and hitNumber to get sessions_atleast_loginCheckout
loginChackout_output_data AS(
  SELECT
    a.date AS date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.sessionId) AS sessions_atleast_loginCheckout 
  FROM
    loginCheckout_index10_pagetype_data AS a
  LEFT JOIN 
    loginCheckout_index43_pagelevel1_data AS b 
  ON
    a.date = b.date AND
    a.sessionId = b.sessionId AND
    a.hitNumber = b.hitNumber
  WHERE
    pagelevel1_login_to_thankyou IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
    date



#table5 - leftjoin table1 with table4 to get all data together
SELECT
  prep.date,
  prep.sessions_atleast_basket,
  log.sessions_atleast_loginCheckout,
  prep.sessions_atleast_payment
FROM
    prepared_data AS prep
  LEFT JOIN
    loginChackout_output_data as log
  ON
    prep.date = log.date AND
```

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the # of CTEs?  In my mind, you are encapsulating different pieces of logic in each one, which will make it easier for your teammates to read (or you in 6 months).  New lines are cheap, brain power is expensive.

Comment: to safe time, I'm currently alone and not very experienced. Also i wasn't sure if there was another way (understandable and logical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit like Inception, but maybe it helps to keep in mind that the input of `unnest()` is an array and the output are table rows ...

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(totals.visits) as sessions
FROM
  `big-query-221916.172008714.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
  AND -- the following two hits.customDimensions.index and associated hits.customDimensions.value appear in the same hits.hitNumber
    (SELECT COUNT(1)>0 as hitsCountMoreThanZero FROM UNNEST(hits) AS h
     WHERE 
       -- index 43, value IN ('login', 'payment', 'order', 'thankyou')
       (select count(1)>0 from unnest(h.customdimensions) where index=43 and value IN ('login', 'payment', 'order', 'thankyou'))
       AND
       -- index 10, value = 'checkout'
       (select count(1)>0 from unnest(h.customdimensions) where index=10 and value='checkout')
    )
GROUP BY
  date
```